# Increasing rows and columns

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, no-computers

Cosmo has arranged the integers $1,2,\ldots,49$ in a $7\times7$ table, so that in each row (left to right) and in each column (top to bottom) the entries occur in increasing order.

> **Questions:**
>   What is the **smallest** possible sum of the numbers in the fourth row in such an arrangement?
>   What is the **largest** possible sum of the numbers in the fourth row in such an arrangement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume a table labelled with columns A-G and rows 1-7

Question A : Smallest total

> Row 4, Column A has 3 cells above it in the same column of the table and all of these must be smaller than cell **4A**, so the smallest it can be is $4$.
>  Row 4, Column B has 3 cells directly above it, along with cell **4A** and all the cells directly above that, making a total of seven cells which must be smaller than **4B**, so the smallest it can be is $8$,
>  Continuing across in this fashion, the lowest total possible is $4+8+12+16+20+24+28 = 112$

Question B : Largest total

> Reversing the approach above, the largest value possible in Row 4, Column G is $46$ as there need to be 3 numbers larger below it in the grid.
>  Row 4, Column F needs 7 number bigger than it, so it can be at most $42$.
>  Continuing gives $22+26+30+34+38+42+46=238$

Examples:

> [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkSUD.png)

Comment: I'd just finished the 'smallest' bit when you posted. Ah well... Your addition's slightly off, though - it's 112, not 116

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat Thanks for the correction, I had typed 28 twice into my addition!

Comment: Can you provide a more rigorous proof ? I mean, intuitively, I can see why your answers make sense.  But I feel that it still needs to be proven more rigorously that these are optimal .